# Equivalent for System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.AddArc in XAML UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

is there any equivalent for System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.AddArc, in Xaml UWP rendering ?

I have tried the below use case in XAML UWP up-to my knowledge.

```
        Path path = new Path();
        PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();
        ArcSegment arcSegment = new ArcSegment();
        arcSegment.IsLargeArc = true;
        arcSegment.Size = new Windows.Foundation.Size(100, 100);
        arcSegment.Point = new Windows.Foundation.Point(100, 100);
        arcSegment.RotationAngle = 180;
        arcSegment.SweepDirection = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
        pathFigure.StartPoint = new Windows.Foundation.Point(100, 100);
        pathFigure.Segments.Add(arcSegment);
        path.Data = pathGeometry;
        path.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        path.StrokeThickness = 2;
        pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);
```

But the above is not 100% equivalent to [System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.AddArc(Rectangle, Single, Single)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any equivalent for System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.AddArc, in Xaml UWP rendering ?

In classical windows form application, we have [`System.Drawing.Drawing2D`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace for drawing graphics. But this namespace is not supported in UWP app. UWP app has its own APIs for drawing graphics. You should be able to draw shapes by APIs under [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes) namespace. More details about how to draw shapes on uwp app please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/drawing-shapes).

The method `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.AddArc` is actually for drawing a arc, which you already found in uwp app you could use adding [`ArcSegment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.arcsegment) instead.

> But the above is not 100% equivalent to System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.AddArc(Rectangle, Single, Single)

UWP app has its own APIs for drawing that it may not have a method that has same method name and same parameters as it in windows form. But you should be able to  use other methods in uwp to implement the same effects. For example, the [`AddArc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142517(v=vs.110).aspx) method has three parameters, `Rectangle` is for defined the x-diameter and y-diameter and the shape location, and `startAngle` and `sweepAngle` for defined the start and end angle. In uwp app, the `ArcSegment` can define the arc x-radius and y-radius by `size` property, and point for define start and end location.

For example, in a windows form, we may use the following code drawing a arc;

```
 protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnPaint(e);
     // Create a GraphicsPath object.
     GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath();
     // Set up and call AddArc, and close the figure.
     Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, 20, 50, 100);
     myPath.StartFigure();
     myPath.AddArc(rect, 0, 180);
     myPath.CloseFigure();
     // Draw the path to screen.
     e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.Red, 3), myPath);
 }
```

In uwp app you can do the same thing in xaml by the following code:

```
 <Path  StrokeThickness="2"  Margin="40,40,0,0" Stroke="Red">
     <Path.Data>
         <PathGeometry>
             <PathFigure IsClosed="True">
                 <PathFigure.Segments>
                     <PathSegmentCollection>   
                         <ArcSegment  Size="25,50" Point="50,0"  IsLargeArc="True"  />  
                     </PathSegmentCollection>
                 </PathFigure.Segments>
             </PathFigure>                 
         </PathGeometry>
     </Path.Data>
 </Path>
```

Or code behind:

```
 private void btnCreatepath_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Path path = new Path();
     PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
     PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();
     ArcSegment arcSegment = new ArcSegment();
     arcSegment.IsLargeArc = true;
     arcSegment.Size = new Windows.Foundation.Size(25, 50);
     arcSegment.Point = new Windows.Foundation.Point(50, 0);
     arcSegment.RotationAngle = 180;
     pathFigure.IsClosed = true;
     pathFigure.Segments.Add(arcSegment);
     path.Data = pathGeometry;
     path.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
     path.StrokeThickness = 2;
     path.Margin = new Thickness(40, 40, 0, 0);
     pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);
     gridroot.Children.Add(path);
 }
```

And the result:

[image]

In a word that you should be able find APIs to draw the same thing which you done in the form.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.